# Ext Js how to change the xtype dynamically

Tags: extjs

I have a border layout whose center panel is defined like the below.

```
     {
       region:'center',
       id:'Center',
       layout:'fit',
       xtype:'gridA'
     }
```

But on click of some button, I need to change the grid to 'gridB' through javascript programmatically. How can this be done.

I tried the following with no success.

```
1) Ext.getCmp('Center').xtype = 'gridB';

2) Ext.getCmp('Center').setxtype('gridB');

3) Ext.getCmp('Center').items.add({xtype:'gridB'});
```

Please suggest me the way through which this can be achieved.

Thanks
Sk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have named the layout as `layout` this should be done like that:

`layout.getComponent('Center').add({xtype:'gridB'});`

Note that you can't change xtype dynamically, you only can use `.add` method.